# Children view controllers must have a common parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition

My app is crashing when I tap on the button continuously. On button tap, I am doing `transitionFlipFromRight` animation.

Here is the code snippet I have written on button action:

```
func transitionBetweenViews() {
    let fromViewController = aController
    let toViewController = bController
    let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = self.viewModel.State == .something ? .transitionFlipFromRight : .transitionFlipFromLeft
    if !self.children.contains(toViewController) {
        fromViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        self.addChild(toViewController)
    }
    self.containerView.fillWithView(toViewController.view)
    self.transition(from: fromViewController, to: toViewController, duration: 0.5, options: options, animations: {
    }, completion: { _ in
        fromViewController.removeFromParent()
        toViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    })
}
```

But I observed that when I changed the `duration` from 0.5 to 0.1 then app is working but animation doesn’t look good.

Here is the crash log:-

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Children view controllers must have a common parent view controller when calling -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incoherent to start the transition when the previous transition is still going on. So simply prevent the button from being tapped while the transition is going on. Just turn off user interaction at the start of the button action, and turn it back on in the completion handler.